# I need to write a batch script that will restart two services, but only start the second service after checking the log file

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a batch script that will restart two services, but it will need to check the log file of the first service for a specific string value before restarting the second service, keep looping back until the sting value is found before starting the second service.

I have very little experience with batch scripting, but I think I need to somehow assign the string value to Var and only if it's the correct value start the second service?

```
@echo off
sc \localhost Stop IMS01


sc \0.0.0.0 stop IMS02


sc \localhost Start IMS01

rem delay of 4mins 
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 240 > nul

:Loop


IF EXIST Find "started and accepting connections" D:\logs\IMS.log
GOTO StartIMS02

IF NOT EXIST Find "started and accepting connections" D:\logs\IMS.log
Goto Loop

:StartIMS02
sc \0.0.0.0 Start IMS02
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I assume that all of your `0.0.0.0` are placeholders for known working code and you just need help with the parsing of the log file? If so:

```
@(
  echo off
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  SET "_Svr1=localhost"
  SET "_Svc1=IMS01"
  SET "_Svr2=0.0.0.0 "
  SET "_Svc2=IMS02"
  SET "_Delay=240"
  SET "_Delay_Loop=30"
  SET "_StringToMatch=started and accepting connections"
)

FOR /L %%L IN (1,1,2) DO (
  ECHO.Stopping: !_Svc%%L! On: !_Svc%%L!
  SC \\!_Svr%%L! Stop !_Svc%%L!
)

ECHO.Starting: %_Svc1% On: %_Svr1%
SC \\%_Svr1% Start %_Svc1%

rem delay of 3 minute(s)
PING 127.0.0.1 -n %_Delay% > nul

:Loop

  rem delay of 1 minute(s)
  PING 127.0.0.1 -n %_Delay_Loop% > nul

  IF EXIST "D:\logs\IMS.log" (
    (
      Find /I "%_StringToMatch%" "D:\logs\IMS.log"
    ) && (
      ECHO.
      ECHO.============================
      ECHO.Success! Found the String "%_StringToMatch%"
      ECHO.
      ECHO. Starting %_Svc2% on %_Svr2%
      SC \\%_Svr2% Start %_Svc2%
    ) || (
      ECHO. Failed to Find the String "%_StringToMatch%"
      ECHO. Looping, will wait another %_Delay_Loop% Seconds before testing again.
      GOTO :Loop
    )
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO Log File Not Found!  Aborting!
  )
GOTO :EOF
```

Now I decided to set a bunch of variable names just for my own sanity, that is all optional, although it does mean we can loop the two services to stop them.

The Logic I have put in place checks if the log file exists, if it does not it aborts the script.

It also adds a 30-second wait on the looping, you can play around with those a lot easier when they are variables IMHO.

I put in some ECHOs to let you keep tabs on what the script is doing they are all optional.

Now the meat of it is I use the FIND /I "String" command to check for the string, a dif it exists we'll start service 2. `&&` is a logical test to see if the result was a success, while as you may have guessed, `||` tests for a fail state.  We have to test for success first or the actions of the fail state could theoretically trigger the success state to run too. (although in your specific case the `GoTo` would break that from happening.)

If the string was not matched w loop again and we'll have our 30 second delay before retry.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thank you so much this is actually what I'm looking for! you you mind me asking what the line "FOR /L %%L IN (1,1,2) DO" is doing? I only ask because I might need to stop more than two services later

Comment: The `FOR /L %%L IN (1,1,2) DO ( )` Is a construct that allows what would be termed a `For J` in C++ the /L option tells the loop to behave as that classic iterative loop type.  We declare in this case the variable to be `%%L` but it could be any of 64 letters or symbols such as %%A (SS64 has a good list of them here: https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) ( - I chose `L` just as a matter of preference to match the `FOR /L`, nothing more)  As for the actual contract the form of it i is `FOR [switch] [options] %%[Letter] IN ([Start],[Step],[Stop]) DO ( )` Which I think shoudl make it more clear.

Comment: @SeanO'Sullivan Specifically given the generalized version I provided in the last comment of `FOR [switch] [options] %%[Letter] IN ([Start],[Step],[Stop]) DO ( )`, the specific `FOR /L %%L IN (1,1,2) DO ( )` Stores the increment value in `%%L`, Initially sets that value to `1`, executes the code within the `DO ( )` section, then increments the value in `%%L` by `1` and executes the DO again,  after which it will terminate as we have reached the stop value of `2`.

Comment: @SeanO'Sullivan  As noted in the original posting I am using this to allow me to have a list of servers/services with `1,2,3...N` on them, and loop through and stop them all without having to write all f their commands separately.  There are other methods of doing this that ca work as well.  If you have a long list that does not need an order to it, you could name the variables `SET "_Svr_[Actual Server IP/FQDN]=[Service Name]"` then later you could loop the output of `SET __Svr_` to get that list and stop/start them all but they would be in alphabetical order.